# Getting warning when using components recursively in VueJS

Tags: recursion, vue.js

I'm making a recursive tree of components in VueJS. I have this kind of line in my **item** component:

```
<item v-for="i in items" v-model="i"></item>
```

It works fine, but Vue is giving me this warning:

> You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will
>   not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the
>   alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an
>   array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.

I'm confused about this warning, as my app seems to be working fine - I can add, move and delete nodes in my item tree just fine. What's up with this error message - should I worry?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that changes to the param `i` passed as the `v-model` for your `<item>` component won't be reflected in the `items` property. This is because `i` is just an alias for the item and not the actual item.

If you don't need `items` to update when the model for each `<item>` component changes, then you don't need to worry. But you probably do want `items` to update since you're passing each element in items as a `v-model`.

In order to properly reference each item and avoid this warning, you can access each element in the array of `items` using the index. Like so:

```
<item v-for="(item, index) in items" v-model="items[index]"></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should worry, because you will not be able to use `i` bind to the model in other contexts, like watchers, or filters, etc.

This is not a good practice and the warning is valid.

Please consider creating an array in your `data` and add the your data to it as objects then do the `v-for` and binding. it is much safer.

I had a similar warning before and I could not deal with variables because they were considered local as the warning